# CheckBox Like radio button in XAML

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I want to design a radio button for selection for true and false values with change in background color its only work for selection but when i click on same its not working following is my style for same, Bellow is my checkbox

```
  <CheckBox Foreground="Black" Content="Save Internet Banking ID" Style="{StaticResource myStyle}"  />
```

Below is my style for same

```
<Style x:Key="myStyle" TargetType="CheckBox">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="CheckBox">
                <RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}"
                            Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                          Style="{StaticResource RadioButtonStyle1}"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Below is my radio button style

```
 <Style x:Key="RadioButtonStyle1" TargetType="RadioButton">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource PhoneRadioCheckBoxBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource PhoneRadioCheckBoxBorderBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource TextStyleLargeFontSize}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="{ThemeResource CheckBoxAndRadioButtonTextPaddingThickness}"/>
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{ThemeResource CheckBoxAndRadioButtonMinWidthSize}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="RadioButton">
                <Grid Background="Transparent">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Container"/>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckBackground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonPressedBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckMark">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonPressedForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckBackground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonDisabledBorderThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckMark">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonDisabledBorderThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckMark">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="UnCheckMark">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="CheckMark">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="UnCheckMark">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate"/>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Grid x:Name="Container" Margin="{ThemeResource PhoneTouchTargetLargeOverhang}">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="25.5"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top">
                            <Ellipse x:Name="CheckBackground" Fill="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25.5" IsHitTestVisible="False" Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" StrokeThickness="{ThemeResource PhoneStrokeThickness}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="25.5"/>
                            <Ellipse x:Name="CheckMark" Fill="Orange" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="20" IsHitTestVisible="False" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="20"/>
                            <Ellipse x:Name="UnCheckMark" Fill="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="20" IsHitTestVisible="False" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="20"/>
                            <TextBlock/>
                        </Grid>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Grid.Column="1" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. When does the background change? and when does it does not? Also if is change in background is all you want